# CSS transition on links with images only

Tags: css, hyperlink, css-transitions

How can I apply transition only on the links which have images instead of text. For example only in the second link:

```
<a href="#">no image</a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://i.qkme.me/35rb4r.jpg"></a>
```

The following CSS will apply transition on all links:

```
a{   
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:    opacity 0.5s;
    -o-transition:      opacity 0.5s;
}

a:hover{
    opacity:0.1;
}
```

I've tried this and doesnt work.

```
a:hover img{
    opacity:0.1;
}
```

Here's jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wg5b3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a > img:hover{
    opacity:0.1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:    opacity 0.5s;
    -o-transition:      opacity 0.5s; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot select a parent element via css. But you really can style the image directly, i.e.

```
a > img {transition: opacity 0.5s;}
a > img:hover {opacity 0.1;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a img:hover {
    opacity:0.1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this as well:

```
a{   
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:    opacity 0.5s;
    -o-transition:      opacity 0.5s;
}

a:hover #hello{
    opacity:0.1;
}

<a href="#">no image</a>
<a href="#" id="hello" ><img src="http://i.qkme.me/35rb4r.jpg"></a>
```